Airflow scheduled DAG randomly not triggering
I have a dag scheduled using EventsTimetable. It ran three time on schedule as expected, and then completely ignored two runs in a row- No failure/skipped in the UI, no alert email. Nothing in the logs either, as if the run was never scheduled at all. The “next run” showed up correctly in the UI before the runs that were skipped.  Today, it magically started running on schedule again. We are running airflow on AKS, but I checked the pods and all seemed to be running normally when the outage occurred.
Any ideas or suggestions on how to debug an issue like this?
